# The usage of 'of' to specify an amount and value

Tags: prepositions, numbers

As a non-native speaker of English, I think we use the "of" term in an interesting way when we define the amount of something. I know that "**The rock has a mass of 50 kg**" is a correct sentence. But, I hardly put its structure in my mind. In "the handle of the door" phrase, the door has a handle and we mean it in this phrase. But what do we mean internally when we say "a mass of 50 kg"? I am not sure if I asked the question right but what is the intuitional meaning behind the "a mass of 50 kg" if "*we use 'of' to combine two nouns when the first noun identifies the feature of the second noun that you want to talk about.*"

Comment: You ask the question in a sufficiently clear manner but you disregard the fact that there are dictionary definitions that have to be checked first; what did the dictionaries tell you? Is it the case that the  available dictionaries online had nothing to say? Was the definition not clear? If the dictionaries do not solve your problem, you have to state this in your query: it is part of a minimum  research that is asked from the posters of questions. Check for instance [OALD 6](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=of):  explain in what way it is wanting.

Comment: Do not limit yourself to one dictionary, and if all of those that you checked provide the same unsatisfatory explanation, quote them.

Comment: I researched the topic on the Internet first, then looked at the dictionaries. I take ".. use 'of' to combine two nouns when the first noun identifies the feature of the second noun that you want to talk about." from collinsdictionary.com for example. The same dictionary also says "You use of to specify an amount, value, or age." as a preposition. I know the usage is correct. But the noun phrase usage of 'of' doesn't match intuitively with specifying the amount or value to me.

Comment: The content of your last comment should be written in your answer, and you should provide the links to the sources so that the readers  can check them.

Comment: As someone commented in response to a recent question; prepositions have multiple uses that can't always be logically explained.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered, but you could compare something like "a bag of apples" or "a handful of rice", which are also a kind of measurement.

Comment: I'm going to close this question as [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of), among other dictionaries too, indicates that *of* has multiple uses. The word has been around since Old English (<10th century). You are welcome to amend your question to address the apparent lack of research and possibly include the [history] or [historical-change] tags if you are actually asking about the history of the word (which also should be clear in your question).

Comment: The OED: "The primary sense was ‘away’, ‘away from’, a sense now obsolete, except in so far as it is retained under the spelling off (see off adv., prep., n., & adj.). All the existing uses of of are derivative; many so remote as to retain no trace of the original sense, and so weakened as to be in themselves the expression of relatively indefinable syntactic relationships. ...

Comment: "The sense-history is exceedingly complicated by reason of the introduction of senses or uses derived from other sources, the mingling of these with the main stream, and the subsequent weakening, which often renders it difficult to assign a particular modern use to its actual source or sources. From its original sense, of was naturally used in the expression of the notions of removal, separation, privation, derivation, origin or source,starting-point, spring of action, cause, agent, instrument, material, and other senses,which involve the notion of ‘taking, coming, arising, or resulting from’.

Comment: "But, even in Old English, this internal development was affected by the translational character of the literature, and the employment of of to render Latin ab, dē, or ex, in constructions where non-literary discourse would not have used it. Of greater significance was its employment from the 11th cent. as the equivalent of French de, itself of composite origin, since it not merely represented Latin dē in its various prepositional uses, but had come to be the substitute in French for the Latin genitive case." And much much more

Comment: Among its uses, the preposition **of** is used to form periphrastic genitive constructions, and in your examples it would be the *descriptive genitive* aka *genitive of description* (an example of itself). E.g. a man of means,  a flight of 30 steps, a weight of 30 kilos, a horse of a different color.